# Resolving an Error 400 with Firebase/Firestore and VueJS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to write an ordering app using Google Firebase as the database to store everything. I attempted to test the connection but keep getting `GET` and `POST` HTTP 400 errors when I submit test data.

I have installed v8.0.0 via NPM. My `firebase.js` file is as follows:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

import { firebaseConfig } from '@/firebaseConfig';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export const dbMenuRef = db.collection("menu");
```

Fire security purposes I keep the object Google generates for configuration containing the keys and such in a separate file. I even tried putting the object in the `firebase.js` file and still got these errors.

The data is structured as follows:

```
newOrder: {
  customerName: 'John Doe',
  customerPhone: '1-800-DRUIDIA',
  items:[{
      itemUPC: '1234567890',
      itemDesc: 'A generic item',
      itemDist: 'The one we always use'
  }, {
      itemUPC: '0987654321',
      itemDesc: 'Another Generic Item',
      itemDist: 'The other one we use'
  }]
}
```

Data is two-way bound to a form. This is working properly and I have the `newOrder` object displayed in the component. This is working just fine as the JSON looks like above.

The following VueJS method is triggered by clicking a "Submit Order" button.

```
addOrder() {
      dbMenuRef.add(this.newOrder)
    }
```

Edit: I am using Firefox Developer Edition latest version.

Second Edit: This apparently works in Chrome, but not Firefox DE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing array as a value to `items` key. If you use dbMenuRef.add, you might want to add as sub-collections. Instead, you can use `.set` if you want to have the entire document added (please refer the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js). Can you try:

```
  addOrder() {
      dbMenuRef
      .doc(this.orderID)
      .set(this.newOrder)
  }
```

Comment: I want the Doc to be automatically generated by Firebase. But I did hardcode one in with `dbMenuRef.doct('test').set(this.newOrder)` and still got the Bad Request error.

Comment: I assume you have used doc instead of doct. It looks like the JSON is malformed can you post the full request/response log (if possible) ?

Comment: Yeah. That was a typo. On a whim, I checked in Chrome and it did work. So now I am wondering why.